# How to solve $(1-x^2)y''-2xy'+2y=0$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I have not taken a course in differential equations but I decided to try and tackle this question I saw and solve for the general solution because why not. That said, I have some observations about the differential equation $(1-x^2)y'' - 2xy'+2y=0$.

$y=Ax$ is a solution to the equation however, I am unsure if I lose any information because $y''=\frac{\,d^2y}{\,dx^2}Ax=0$. When I set $y(x)=Axu(x)=Aux$,(I think this is how you solve second order with variable coefficients) I got to the point $$\begin{align*} u''(x-x^3)+2u'(1-2x^2) &= u''(x-x^3)+2u'(1-3x^2)+2u'x^2\\&=\frac{\,d}{\,dx}\big[u'(x-x^3)\big]+2u'(1-x^2)\\&=0 \end{align*}$$

Then I let $u'=w$ and got $w'(x-x^3)=-w(3-5x^2)$, separated variables and integrated to get $u=Ce^{\frac{1}{x^3(1-x)(1+x)}}$ and $y=ACxe^{\frac{1}{x^3(1-x)(1+x)}}$

I am not sure if this is correct, but it seems reasonable.

Also, $(1-x^2)y''-2xy' + 2y = \frac{\,d}{\,dx}[y'(1-x^2)] + 2y=0$, and this didn't seem to get me anywhere but, by factoring out $(1-x^2)$, I was able to make some more inferences:

For $x\ne \pm 1$,

$$\begin{align*}\bigg(y''-\frac{2xy'}{1-x^2}+\frac{2y}{1-x^2}\bigg)&=\bigg(\frac{\,d}{\,dx}y'+2\frac{\,d}{\,dx}\bigg[\frac{yx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\bigg]\bigg)\\&=\frac{\,d}{\,dx}\bigg(y'+2\frac{yx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\bigg)\\&=0 \end{align*}$$

I wasn't sure if I could, but I went ahead and integrated both sides with respect to x to get $$y'+2\frac{yx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=C_1 $$

I then assumed $C_1=0$ to turn it into a separable differential equation because I don't know what to do with the above expression and , as expected, upon checking, this was the incorrect answer.

I was just curious how to solve this for the general solution and tried to take on a challenging problem to pass some time. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, $\frac{d}{dx}\left(y^\prime+\frac{2yx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right)=y^{\prime\prime}+\frac{2xy^\prime}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}+\frac{2y}{(1-x^2)^{3/2}}$, so your first-order ODE is wrong. See [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+%281-x%5E2%29d%5E2y%2Fdx%5E2-2xdy%2Fdx%2B2y%3D0) for the correct solution. (I recommend the substitution $u=\tfrac{1+x}{1-x}$.)

Comment: oops. Had the quotient rule messed up. @J.G.

Comment: However, when a problem *does* reduce to that or a similar ODE, see [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegratingFactor.html).

Comment: I suggest trying the Ansatz $y=c_0 + c_1x + c_2x^2+ c_3x^3+\dots,$  substituting this $y$ into the differential equation, and then solving for the undetermined coefficients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Alpha](http://y(x)%20=%20c_1%20x%20+%20c_2%20(-1/2%20x%20(log(1%20-%20x)%20-%20log(x%20+%201))%20-%201)) identifies it as Legendre's equation and gives the solution
$$y(x) = c_1 x + c_2 (-x (\log(1 - x)/2 - \log(x + 1)) - 1)$$
It offers step by step if you have the right account